# Inno Setup: How to automatically run program after /verysilent install?

Tags: automation, inno-setup

How to automatically run my program after performing a `/verysilent` install?

I can automatically run my program after a normal install by using `DisableFinishedPage=yes` in the `[Setup]` section (that disables the finish page and will run the program immediately after install, without user intervention).

However if I use the `/verysilent` parameter that won't work: my program installs but won't automatically run afterwards.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently it's working fine now. I just removed `skipifsilent` flag from the `Run` section!